# Error GLSL incorrect version 450

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glew

I have a certain OpenGL application which I compiled in the past but now can't in the same machine. The problem seems to be in the fragment shader not compiling properly.

I'm using:

- Glew 2.1.0
- Glfw 3.2.1

Also all necessary context is being created on the beginning of the program. Here's how my program creation function looks like:

```
std::string vSource, fSource;
try 
{
    vSource = getSource(vertexShader, "vert");
    fSource = getSource(fragmentShader, "frag");
}
catch (std::runtime_error& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}

GLuint vsID, fsID;
try
{
    vsID = compileShader(vSource.c_str(), GL_VERTEX_SHADER); //Source char* was checked and looking good
    fsID = compileShader(fSource.c_str(), GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
}
catch (std::runtime_error& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; //incorrect glsl version 450 thrown here
}
GLuint programID;
try
{
    programID = createProgram(vsID, fsID); //Debugging fails here
}
catch (std::runtime_error& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}

glDeleteShader(vsID);
glDeleteShader(fsID);

return programID;
```

My main:

```
/* ---------------------------- */
/* OPENGL CONTEXT SET WITH GLEW */
/* ---------------------------- */
static bool contextFlag = initializer::createContext(vmath::uvec2(1280, 720), "mWs", window);
std::thread* checkerThread = new std::thread(initializer::checkContext, contextFlag);

/* --------------------------------- */
/* STATIC STATE SINGLETON DEFINITION */
/* --------------------------------- */
Playing Playing::playingState; //Failing comes from here which tries to create a program



/* ---- */
/* MAIN */
/* ---- */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    checkerThread->join();
    delete checkerThread;

    Application* app = new Application();
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the looking of an example of the fragmentShader file:

```
#version 450 core

out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = vec4(0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0);
}
```

And this is what I catch as errors:

```
[Engine] Glew initialized! Using version: 2.1.0
[CheckerThread] Glew state flagged as correct! Proceeding to mainthread!

Error compiling shader: ERROR: 0:1: '' :  incorrect GLSL version: 450
ERROR: 0:7: 'fColor' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:7: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'const 4-component vector of float' to 'float'
```

My specs are the following:

- Intel HD 4000
- Nvidia GeForce 840M

I shall state that I compiled shaders in this same machine before. I can't do it anymore after a disk format. However, every driver is updated.

Comment: Are you sure your graphics drivers are up-to-date? Both of them support GLSL version 450

Comment: I couldn't find info for the Intel card, but the Nvidia one should definitely support GLSL 450. Have you tried running your program with your Nvidia card? (Usually Windows defaults to the Intel one, so check that)

Comment: @Asesh Yesterday when this problem started to annoy me I checked all the drivers. I even rolled them back and used nvidia's panel to install the latest ones

Comment: @banex Yes I know windows usually does that. I have been running the program using the `run with graphics processor` option. Currently using Visual Studio 2017. Unless using that option in the shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: It could still be using Intel's graphics card. Go to desktop, right click, choose NVIDIA control panel, manage 3D settings. Now from preferred graphics processor choose NVIDIA and try again. Anyways, like I said your Intel graphics card support that shader model

Comment: @Asesh The `run with graphics processor` option is not working correctly. You're right. Choosing the NVIDIA as globally preferred is working. As what has been said about Intel HD 4000 having support for `OpenGL 4.5` could be outdated which is possible since I didn't pay much attention to them.

Comment: HD 4000 (Ivy Bridge) supports 4.0 on windows and 4.2 on linux. 4.5 is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments the problem seemed to be with a faulty option of running the IDE with selected `graphics card`. As windows defaults the integrated Intel HD 4000 card, switching the NVIDIA card to the default preferred one by the OS fixed the problem.